# split function in jquery is not working

Tags: jquery, split

I want to split the value from select boxes because i have to show the total price to the client and also send mail to the admin. if i don't use split the values then i cant send the select options labels to the admin for order proceeding. I have tried my best efforts but i failed..... i am asking this question again... please help me in this matter

```
 <div id="target">
                <table cellpadding="10">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
              <div>
                <label>Choose Currency</label>
                <select id="currency" class="shopEssaySelect" name="txtCurrency" required>
                  <option selected disabled value="">Choose ...</option>
                  <?php echo ShowCurrencies(); ?>

                </select>
              </div>

              <div>
                <label>Type of Paper</label>
                <select id="category" class="shopEssaySelect" name="txtPaperType" required>
                  <option selected disabled value="">Choose ...</option>
                  <?php echo ShowCategory(); ?>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label>Academic Level</label>
                <select id="type" class="shopEssaySelect" name="txtAcademicLevel" required>
                  <option selected disabled value="">Choose ...</option>
                   <?php echo ShowType(); ?>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label>Deadline</label>
                <select id="deadline" class="shopEssaySelect" name="txtDeadline" required>
                  <option selected disabled value="">Choose ...</option>
                   <?php echo ShowDeadline(); ?>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label>Service Type</label>
                <select id="servicetype" class="shopEssaySelect" name="txtServiceType" required>
                  <option selected disabled value="">Choose ...</option>
                   <?php echo ShowServiceType(); ?>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label>Line Spacing</label>
                <select id="linespacing" class="shopEssaySelect" name="txtLineSpacing" required>
                  <option selected disabled value="">Choose ...</option>
                   <?php echo ShowLineSpacing(); ?>
                </select>
              </div>
                <div>
                 <label>Paper Format</label>
                 <div class="paper-format">
                 &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="txtPaperFormat" value="MLA">MLA
                 <input type="radio" name="txtPaperFormat" value="APA">APA
                 <input type="radio" name="txtPaperFormat" value="Chicago">Chicago / Turabian
                 <input type="radio" name="txtPaperFormat" value="Harvard">Harvard
                 <input type="radio" name="txtPaperFormat" value="Other">Other
                 </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div><!-- end of target -->




    // jquery code is here 


    function updateTotal(){ 
        currency            = $("#currency").val();
        currency_array      = currency.split("/");
        currency_percentage = currency_array[0];
        currency_symbol     = currency_array[1];

        $("#curr-symbol").text(currency_symbol);    

        // from here split does not work
        paper_values        = $("#category").val();
        paper_array         = paper_values.split("/");
        paper               = paper_array[0];

        type_values         = $("#type").val();
        type_array          = type_values.split("/");
        type_percentage     = type_array[0];

        deadline_values         = $("#deadline").val();
        deadline_array          = deadline_values.split("/");
        deadline_percentage     = deadline_array[0];        

        service_values          = $("#servicetype").val();
        service_array           = service_values.split("/");
        service_percentage      = service_array[0];     

        // but from here split  works   
        spacing             = $("#linespacing").val();
        spacing_array       = spacing.split("/");
        spacing_percentage  = spacing_array[0];
        spacing_words       = spacing_array[1];

        type        = (paper * type_percentage) / 100;
        deadline    = (paper * deadline_percentage) / 100;
        servicetype = (paper * service_percentage) / 100;
        linespacing = (paper * spacing_percentage) / 100;

        currency = (paper * currency_percentage);               

        words   = Number($("#numberOfPages").val());

        counted_words = words * spacing_words;

        $("#totalwords").text(counted_words);

        total_amount = (paper + type + deadline + servicetype + linespacing + currency) * words;

        if (!isNaN(total_amount)){
                total_amount = Math.round((paper + type + deadline + servicetype + linespacing + currency) * words);
            }
            else {
                total_amount ="0";
            }

        $("#total").text(total_amount);
      }

       $(".shopEssaySelect").change(function(){
        updateTotal();
      })

      $("#numberOfPages").on("input", function(event) {
    updateTotal();
          })
```

```
    // php code is here

         function ShowCategory()
            {

                $sql = "SELECT pd_id, c.cat_id,base_price, cat_name, pd_name
                        FROM tbl_bbproduct p, tbl_bbcategory c
                        WHERE p.cat_id = c.cat_id
                        ORDER BY cat_name";

                 $result = mysql_query($sql);

                 $category_name = array();           

                 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                 {
                     $category_name[$row['cat_name']][] = $row;  

                 }
                 foreach ($category_name as $key => $values)
                 {
                     echo '';
                     foreach ($values as $row) 
                     {

                         echo ''.$row['pd_name'].'';

                     }
                     echo '';

                 }


            }

            function ShowType()
            {

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_academic_level";          
                $res = mysql_query($sql);
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
                {
                    echo '' . $row['level_name'] . '';
                }
                return ;
            }

            function ShowDeadline()
            {

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_deadline";
                $res = mysql_query($sql);
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
                {
                    echo '' . $row['deadline_name'] . '';
                }
                return ;
            }

            function ShowServiceType()
            {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_service_type";
                $res = mysql_query($sql);

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
                {
                    echo  '' . $row['service_name'] . '';
                }
                return ;
            }

            function ShowLineSpacing()
            {

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_line_spacing";
                $res = mysql_query($sql);
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
                {
                    echo  '' . $row['spacing_name'] . '';
                }
                return ;
            }

            function ShowCurrencies()
            {

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_currencies";
                $res = mysql_query($sql);
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
                {
                    echo  '' . $row['currency_name'] . '';
                }
                return ;
            }
```

Comment: please post the final html and only the section of JS code  . Please remove  the unwanted  sections from your code

Comment: What is the Category values you are binding into select options.